# \Printbibliography is not Showing list of References

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am using the code shown below, to generate the numeric references in IEEE style, but instead of numbers, it gives the output in alphabetic names. Also it is not printing the references list.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
    using the below package for referencing  
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

Below is my .bib file
        \addbibresource{References.bib}

```
    \input{Chapters/Literature}
    \printbibliography
```

Comment: To get IEEE style for biblatex, try `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`. To diagnose why your reference list is not printed it would be good if you could add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: using \usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex} is also not solving my problem

Comment: Then please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)!